# Found my child's LG phone but can't remember unlock pattern

Tags: locked-out, pattern-lock

Found my child's LG phone which was lost months ago. Can not remember pattern to unlock. What do I do?

Comment: Did it have a Google account associated with it? You could use https://www.google.com/android/find and lock the device with a new PIN. Otherwise, if it has no Google account you can factory default, but if it has one and you can't access the Google account the device will be bricked (probably permanently).

Comment: Otherwise, our [locked-out tag wiki](/tags/locked-out/info) might be helpful to you. [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](/q/35847/16575) (also linked from there) has the most comprehensive collection of approaches, though some of them might no longer work. Best luck!